# OpenBSD: is safe to delete /usr/src?

Tags: openbsd, source

After I successfully upgraded OpenBSD, I wanted to upgrade my sources. I want to know, is it safer to delete `/usr/src` and then extract `src.tar.gz`, or is it better to preserve the already existing `/usr/src` and then extract `src.tar.gz`? Will there be any repercussions caused by deleting `/usr/src`, or can I simply replace it?

Comment: When in OpenBSD land, 'fresh' is often the best route, in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete `/usr/src` and extract the new `src.tgz`.

Comment: It would be useful to explain why you believe this is the better of the two options. As it stands it has little value.

Comment: `tar` doesn't delete the non-existent files in the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

#### `/usr/src`

Replacing `/usr/src` with your own copy will work just fine, as long as you can make sure to iron out any small problems that might be caused by doing so. One of those problems might be dependencies and version differences between the sources you copied and the versions that applications might need, although presumably you know what you are doing if you are adding in the sources to your filesystem.

#### Preservation or Replacement?

Now we get to the part that you are waiting for: should you preserve `/usr/src` or replace it with the `src` directory from `src.tar.gz`?In fact, it is really personal preference, although as a more hassle-free method, I would recommend replacing `src`. The reason for this is simple: would you rather extract an archive, delete a directories contents, move the extracted directories contents to the old directory, and then delete the archived directory and the archive *or* simply just delete a directory, unarchive a directory, and then delete the archive? There is nothing special about your existing `/usr/src` directory (unless you have symbolic links interacting with it, or there are programs that search it (e.g. `sh` looking in it because of your `$PATH`, although that example could be solved incredibly easily). Overall this means that it is up to you to evaluate whether it is worth the extra work to do a contents transfer from the archive directory to `/usr/src`, or if it would be better simply to replace it.

#### More Information

To get more information on `/usr/src` and `src.tar.gz` go here:
[Fetching Sources(See Pre-loading...)](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/faq5.html#BldGetSrc)
[OpenBSD From Source(Explains `src.tar.gz`)](http://slides.cobug.org/view/OpenBSD%20From%20Source#/)